# Prestashop configure product attribute without stock

Tags: prestashop

In PrestaShop, I saw that attributes are involved in stocks calculation. Is it possible to avoid that? 
Here is an example: my shop sells a product with the option "Giftbox". The gift box has a cost of 2€, but it has not a stock. In the admin product page, Prestashop asks me for a stock, but the gift box is not related to the product itself.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use Prestashop >= 1.7 you can set Gitf Options without attributes. You can find it in Preferences->Orders.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I saw the gift option but the problem exists for other kind attributes. Example: I sell a bracelet 19 cm length. Some customer has a bigger (or smaller) wrist, so I need to ask how much centimetres to add. In this case, each centimetre has a cost, but it does not have a stock.